# обрез строки jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

как с помощью jquery если в одном из классов news-tags текст больше 40 символов, обрезать его до 38 символов, и добавить 2 точки?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

разобрался

```
function substr_tags() {
  $('.news-tags').each(function () {
     var text = $(this).text();
    if(text.length > 40) {
      text = text.slice(0,30);
      text += '..';
      $(this).text(text);
    }
  });
}
```